# Minimax Algorithm: Why make rating negative?

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
/* finds the best move for the current player given the state of the game.
 * depth parameter and MAX_DEPTH are used to limit the depth of the search for games
 * that are too difficult to analyze in full detail (like chess)
 * returns best move by storing an int in variable that rating points to.
 * we want to make the move that will result in the lowest best move for the position after us(our opponent)
 */
moveT findBestMove(stateT state, int depth, int &rating) {
    Vector<moveT> moveList;
    generateMoveList(state, moveList);
    int nMoves = moveList.size();
    if (nMoves == 0) cout << "no move??" << endl;
    moveT bestMove;
    int minRating = WINNING_POSITION + 1; //guarantees that this will be updated in for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < nMoves && minRating != LOSING_POSITION; i++) {
        moveT move = moveList[i];
        makeMove(state, move);
        int curRating = evaluatePosition(state, depth + 1);
        if (curRating < minRating) {
            bestMove = move;
            minRating = curRating;
        }
        retractMove(state, move);
    }
    rating = -minRating;
    return bestMove;
}

/* evaluates the position by finding the rating of the best move in that position, limited by MAX_DEPTH */
int evaluatePosition(stateT state, int depth) {
    int rating;
    if (gameIsOver(state) || depth >= MAX_DEPTH) {
        return evaluateStaticPosition(state);
    }
    findBestMove(state, depth, rating);
    return rating;
}
```

This is my code for implementing a minimax algorithm to play a perfect game of tic tac toe against a computer. The code works and there are many other helper functions not show here. I understand the nature of the algorithm, however I am having a hard time fully wrapping my head around the line at the end of the findBestMove() function:

```
rating = -minRating;
```

This is what my book says: The negative sign is included because the perspective has shifted: the positions were evaluated from the point- of-view of your opponent, whereas the ratings express the value of a move from your own point of view. A move that leaves your opponent with a negative position is good for you and therefore has a positive value.
But when we call the function initially, it is from the computers perspective. I guess when we evaluate each position, this function is being called from our opponent's perspective and that is why? Could someone give me more insight into what is going on recursively and exactly why the rating needs to be negative at the end.
As always thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine two positions, A and B, where A is better for player a and B is better for player b.  When player a evaluates these positions, eval(A) > eval(B), but when play b does, we want eval(A) < eval(B), but don't.  If b instead compares -eval(A) with -eval(B), we get the desired result, for the very reasons your book says.

Comment: i guess I am confused about then the comparison that player b does happens. because when evaluating every move for player a, the for loop hasn't finished executing yet, so rating is still positive. Is it that when you call that function in evaluatePosition() it needs to store the rating as - so that when the initial execution of findBestMove picks back up, the rating is correct?

Comment: `findBestMove` calls `evaluafePosition`, which calls `findBestMove`, which (however deep things go there), will eventually return a rating *that has been negated*.